# Play Store crashes when StartApp interstitial ad clicked

Tags: android, startapp

I have an interstitial ad in my app from StartApp. The ad is loaded when the app is exited. Whenever the ad is clicked, Google PLay Store is launched and I get the message that Play Store has crashed.

I followed the instructions exactly as told in the StartApp GitHub page.

This is the error message I get on Android Monitor:

```
01-26 23:36:18.303 17720-17720/com.sanath.bunkmaster E/chromium: [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(104)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::PasswordManagerDriver
01-26 23:36:19.024 17720-17720/com.sanath.bunkmaster W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 17720
```

This is my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.ads.list3d.List3DActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />

    <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.activities.OverlayActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />

    <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.activities.FullScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />

    <service android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.common.metaData.PeriodicMetaDataService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.common.metaData.BootCompleteListener" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Nadav from StartApp.

It seems like the issue you are experiencing is specific to your app, as we've never experienced it before. Therefore, it requires further investigation by our support team, which will need to check your specific app. Please contact us through the developers portal or at support@startapp.com and provide as many details as possible which will help us reproduce the issue, along with your manifest file, the activity in which you've integrated our ad, and a full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: After further investigation we located the problem and fixed it. it's wasn't related to our SDK directly. Sorry for the inconvenience.